# Regular Expression - Detect alphanumerical strings not surrounded by non-alphanumerical strings

Tags: regex

I have a following string:

> aaa bbb() !ccc ddd efef

I want to detect all instances of "clean" alphanumerical words, that is "aaa", "ddd", "efef" that have no other characters before and the end of the word. String can be any alphanumerical character surrounded by any non-alphanumerical characters.

I can do it with four different regular expressions"

1. `\s(\w+)`
2. `^\w+\s`
3. `\s\w+$`
4. `^\w+$`

but how to do it in a single expression?

Comment: And just like that I solved it: 

"(^|\s)(\w+)($|\s)"

Answer (score 2):

Use the `|` or operator:

```
(^|\s)\w+(\s|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: If your original string is `$str`, You can use `\s\w\s` pattern on ' ' . $str . ' '

Comment: That will for example match the `bbb` part of `bbb()` and give a false positive.